# QGIS Graphic modeler: Loading in all the layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Currently I have special script/model, where I convert a geoJSON feature collection to some seperate shapefiles.

There was small pre step and prerequisite, that I want to eliminate, normally we load this GeoJSON file into QGIS by loading all the layers in by adding it as a datasource, either using the QGIS Browser or manage data sources (CTRL+L). The we specify the points, line and polygons that go trought the script.

You would think I could just select this file, as a vector layer and then use the "Load in Project Layer" algorithm to make it much more easier.

**Sadly it will only load one of the features of the GeoJSON** (for some unknown reasons this is only the points). I would use the "File/Map" Parameter but that sadly does not connect to my script at all because that parameter is not considered a layer file.

So how create an algorithm script do I do "Load in Project Layer" but with a feature collection, loading all the layers in the feature collection?

Edit: I have found a possible solution for now, however there is one limitation with it. I will post this solution later when I get the time.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging around and being creative I have kind of found my solution to my problem.

While the there is an geometry by expressions algorithm, it cannot directly connect to a File/Map Parameter. Whoever you still can by **Expression.** Which is something I should have realized earlier, but to be honest I did not think it would work.

If you add an File/folder Parameter and name it you can address to it with

```
@file/folder parameter name
```

If you refer to a folder and want to add a specific file then you have to do this expression:

```
@map || '\\file.fileextension'
```

As for the three main geometry types you can get them with Geometry by expression.

[image]

1. False Error noticing in the log

While the script is running you will get the error this petuclar error. **That the object does not have that specific geometry.**

I can confirm that this is normal though, the object count remains the same. It just because all three expression are running separately after each other not together after each other. That you get this error.

To Illustrate: You are starting with 1000 objects consisting of 750 Polygons, 125 points and lines.

What happens is that each geometry always starts from 1000 objects, so lets say you do the Polygon selection first, the two other algorithms do not take in the Geometry's that were "*rejected*" but always start at those 1000 objects. If now the exact formula of how I can lets say do:

```
$geometry = polygon
```

I would have used that but I do not know how the write expression exactly. Help would be **appreciated.**

2. Tables without geometry/rasters in the file.

This script does not count for Files without geometry or even rasters for that matter. I would have to find another way for it. I will ask this later.