# Exported QGIS model does not work: Invalid input error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

This question is linked to this one:
[QGIS Graphic modeler: Loading in all the layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373835/qgis-graphic-modeler-loading-in-all-the-layers)

I have a very complex model which converts a specific file (pmkl.json) which is a feature collection of points lines and polygons. To its specifics based on theme ( a combination of Refactor and attribute selection algorithms). There are three inputs:

PMKL File = Which is where I browse to the PMKL.Json File to convert.
Target Location = Where the Shapefiles will be saved
CRS = CRS of the target shapefiles.

It is in the PKML File where the filtering of geometry happens, normally filtering by geometry works only with Vector layer. But I managed to get around it to address a file by using an expression.

But when I try to export the model as a script and run it: I get an invalid input.

[image]

Here is the code below that is relevant how do I solve this? Note as a model this thing works fine, but as Python script it does not. I want to make it a standalone application.

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : ODCM KLIP Omzetter
Group : ODCM KLIP Omzetter
With QGIS : 31401
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFile
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterCrs
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterBoolean
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
import processing

class OdcmKlipOmzetter(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile('PKMLBestand', 'PMKL Bestand', behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.File, fileFilter='Alle bestanden (*.json*)', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile('Mapvanuitgepaktezipbestand', 'Doel Locatie', behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.Folder, fileFilter='Alle bestanden (*.*)', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterCrs('crs', 'CRS', defaultValue='EPSG:31370'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterBoolean('VERBOSE_LOG', 'Verbose logging', optional=True, defaultValue=False))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(71, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Filter by geometry type
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': QgsExpression('@PKMLBestand ').evaluate(),
            'LINES': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'POINTS': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'POLYGONS': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FilterByGeometryType'] = processing.run('native:filterbygeometry', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```